# Cakephp REST Api print last query

Tags: php, rest, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am getting below error whenever try to print last query in my REST api controller.

> Error: Call to undefined method ApiController::getDatasource() File:
>   /var/www/html/app/Controller/ApiController.php Line: 734

Here is code

```
    $result = $this->Article->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('Article.active' => 1),
        'limit' => $limit, 'offset' => $start,
        'updated' => 'desc'
    ));

    $dbo = $this->getDatasource();
    $logs = $dbo->getLog();
    pr($result); die;
```

Query is working fine. 
I created this rest controller by [tutorial](http://miftyisbored.com/complete-restful-service-client-cakephp-tutorial/). Let me know if you need more.

Comment: one down vote!! why???

Comment: Well, it's not my downvote, but if I were to guess, then I'd say, maybe because the problem is so obvious - there is no such method on a controller, which is what the message is stating. If you check the docs, you'll see that `getDataSource()` is a model method (also available on the connection manager).

Comment: @ndm Just like other models I have Api model too. and `getDataSource()` is working in other models and controllers well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$log = $this->Article->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);       
debug($log);
```

Comment: Thanks, its working but can you please tell me what is wrong in my code.

Comment: `getDataSource` is a method of model object, it's not called from `$this` in controller, you can call from `$this->YourModel->getDataSource()`. Your code is correct if you calll from `Article` class, not `ApiController`. Please mark as best answer if you think I've helped.